# How to add new browser tab

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

It won't go to a new browser tab, is my code wrong?

```
function getWaterMeterList() {
    // alert("ON");
    var BillingPeriod = $('#BillingPeriod').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/DataEntryWater/WaterMeterAlphaListReport',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'BillingPeriod': BillingPeriod },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (a) {
            $(location).attr('href', a)
            a.preventDefault();
        },
        error: function (err) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's urggent!!!!1 to listen to @DragandDrop! Panic!

Comment: @joebentapel: please desist from begging and shouting. Use your time while you wait for replies to improve your question. What is a "tab" here? Do you mean a browser tab or a tab in your web UI? Is `getWaterMeterList()` called when you expect it to be? Is an AJAX operation started? Does the `success` handler get called? Have you looked at your Network browser panel or JavaScript panel to examine what is happening?

Comment: Remember we cannot see your screen and we do not have access to your web page or your `/DataEntryWater/WaterMeterAlphaListReport` endpoint. We are completely blind except for what information you provide to us.

Comment: a new browser tab

Comment: if i run the code its success but it doesn't go to a new tab. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for might be:

```
window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
```

And in your code:

```
function getWaterMeterList() {
  // alert("ON");
  var BillingPeriod = $('#BillingPeriod').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/DataEntryWater/WaterMeterAlphaListReport',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'BillingPeriod': BillingPeriod },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (a) {
      var win = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank')
      if(win) {
        win.focus(); /if tab is open, change focus there.
      }
    },

    error: function (err) {
      // do stuff here
    }

  });
}
```